# Why does 3.toString() throw a syntax exception and 3..toString() works fine?

Tags: javascript

why in javascript 3.toString() throws exception and 3..toString() works fine?
I saw it in a funny presentation about javascript but I cannot find the info WHY.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because a decimal point is a valid portion of a number, so the first dot is considered numeric, the second is for chaining.

If you'd prefer to avoid the double-period you could instead do:

```
(3).toString();
```

Or:

```
'' + 3;
```

Or:

```
String(3);
```